# What are some night sky objects I could see with my Celestron UpClose 20x50 Porro Binocular?

Tags: amateur-observing, observational-astronomy, bortle-scale, binoculars

I bought [this binocular](http://www.opticsplanet.com/celestron-binoculars-upclose-71144.html) because I've read countless times that one should start with a pair of binoculars before diving into telescopes. I've seen details of the moon and I can notice Venus round shape on some nights. I also saw Jupiter and it's two larger moons, as faint as the faintest stars, but this was on a beach trip so the sky was clearer than what I'm used to.

I live on a place with a **7** or **6** on the [**Bortle Scale**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bortle_scale), is there something else I should try to see?

Comment: Here's a whole club dedicated to observing with binoculars:
http://www.astromax.org/aa02401.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the season you can try different objects. Try large star clusters and nebulae:

- The Pleiades
- Orion nebula
- Andromeda galaxy
- M13 globular cluster

Also double stars like epsilon Lyrae.

It helps to have a foto tripod and an adaptor for the binoculars. Gives much better view when the binoculars are resting on the tripod.

Comment: Yes, a tripod is neccesary since even my own heart beats get in the way by moving the binocular.

Comment: There used to be a very good reference guide for this: [Deep Sky Travel Atlas](http://www.oculum.de/oculum/titel_en.asp?ID=1612201314283467&Nr=35). I have it, however I think it is out of print and it was also in German. It's mostly maps and tables, so the language is not so important... It marks objects as being suitable for binoculars or small telescopes.

Comment: Update: It seems there is a similar book being done by the same publisher: http://www.oculum.de/sites/deepskyatlas/site/dsa.asp --  May be worth checking out.

Answer (score 2):

Try galaxies like Andromeda, and clouds like Orion's sword, as a start.